# Preventing duplicate execution with infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling for my Instagram-like Rails app. However, the piece of jQuery jode that's being executed to render the next page of posts to be rendered is being executed twice.

I tried adding a hack, but it's not entirely effective.

Here's the code:

```
var exec = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#paginator').length) {
        var url = $('#load_more').attr('href');
        if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50 && !exec) {
            exec = true;
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                $('#paginator').append('<div class="spinner"></div>');
                $.getScript(url);
            }).done(function(){ exec = false; });
        }
    }
});
```

The part that's being repeated is obviously the duplicate ajax request so the posts chunk is being appended twice.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, checking document height vs window height will not work in some browsers. So instead, extend jQuery to check if `#load_more` or any other element you want to trigger the pagination is in view, via a new jQuery method called `inView`. Second, use `$.active` to see how many active ajax requests are happening. if it's 0 you can trigger the infinite scroll:

```
$.fn.inView = function(){

    var rect = this[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );

};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#paginator').length) {
        var url = $('#load_more').attr('href');
        if (url && $('#load_more').inView() && $.active == 0) {
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                $('#paginator').append('<div class="spinner"></div>');
                $.getScript(url);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't really get how `inView` works... And yeah it works, but it loads more comments too fast, I just want them to be loaded when reaching the end of the page when scrolling, how could I do that?

Comment: @dabadaba also, you could simply leave out this in favor of your example. the key thing here in context of your problem is using `$.active` to see if an ajax request is already in progress.

Comment: Thank you, the $.active == 0 did the trick for me!